# Can not create rust library for python

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to make a python module in rust. I am continuing to fail to get the files that I need to generate. I followed this tutorial almost exactly.

https://mycognosist.github.io/tutorial-rust-python-lib.html

Here is my toml file.

```
name = "pylib"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Atops"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "status"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies.cpython]
version = "0.5"
features = ["extension-module"]
```

Here is the code for lib.rs

```
extern crate cpython;

use cpython::{PyResult, Python, py_fn, py_module_initializer};

pub extern fn hello(_py: Python, val: String) -> PyResult<String> {
    match &*val {
        "hello" => Ok("world".to_string()),
        _ => Ok("afdfs".to_string()),
    }
}

py_module_initializer!(status, initstatus, Pyinit_status, |py, m|{
    m.add(py, "__doc__", "asdhgdfs")?;
    m.add(py, "hello", py_fn!(py, hello(val: String)))?;
    Ok(())
});
```

I navigate to the appropriate folder with my cargo.toml file and use cargo build --release, as specified in the tutorial. It finishes with a few warnings about certain things being "not FFI-safe". When it finishes a new folder is created called "target". I go through there to where the files for the library should be, but the appropriate files don't seem to have been generated. I have these.

[target\release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA3Y4.png)

These don't seem to be usable for me. I am not sure what I have done wrong.

I copied every single one of these files to another folder and tried importing them in python. This did not work. I tried changing them to .so files, this did not work. It seems that windows is supposed to output a dll here, but the dll file did not work when attempting to import. It did not work as a dll file or a so file. I am not sure what to do here. Also, it seems that when these files are generated in every other tutorial or guide I see, there is a "lib" prefix on the name of each. I get no such prefix.

Comment: You did a great job of telling us how you got to where you are, but you forgot to tell us how you attempted to use the libraries (and how you decided that they were unusable)  Was there an error, did you need `.so` files instead of `.dll` files?  Did they do the wrong thing?  Don't focus on answering my questions, focus on describing the problem you encountered in your own words.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I have edited the question to be more clear about that.

Comment: Maybe you should follow [this page](https://pyo3.rs/v0.15.1/), which seems much more up-to-date than the tutorial you found.

Answer (score 0):

A `dll` file contains shared object code for COFF systems (like Windows) while a `so` file generally contains shared object code for ELF (and other) systems like Linux.

Renaming them will not work under any circumstance.  If you have one and need the other, you need to rebuild them on the correct, matching, operating system.

I think you might be following instructions for Linux (due to the lib prefixes) on a Windows machine and then expecting some of the instructions to work.  They might work, if you can identify all the "changes" between the platform and modify the Linux instructions to match the Windows platform; but until you know how to translate one environment's instructions to the other, it might be easier if you just find a set of Windows instructions that only refer to `dll` files and don't mention `so` files.

Comment: The linked tutorial doesn't appear Linux-specific, but it *is* four years old, which is quite a lot in Rust and Python time. (For example it uses Python 2.7.)

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you for sparing me the read of the tutorial.  I had to hang the lights for Christmas.    Why don't you post an answer stating that their tutorial is old, and they probably would be better served using the one you've offered in the comments?  I'll be happy to delete this shot in the dark afterwards and would love to upvote your solution!

Comment: You're welcome. :) I refrained from posting an answer because I'd prefer an answer to contain at least somewhat authoritative information. As I've never used any Python<->Rust bindings, nor do I use Rust on Windows, I could only speculate, which is more appropriate for comments than for answers.